# [SOLVED] Remove all ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, i am trying to install a package (https://github.com/erik-nelson/blam) which says in its instructions:

```
This repository contains two ROS workspaces (one internal, one external). The build process is proctored by the update script. To build, first make sure that you do not have any other ROS workspaces in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, then clone the repository and from the top directory execute

./update
```

My question is, to do that I should delete from my .bashrc the following lines?

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

However when I do echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH I obtain

/home/dan/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

should I also remove the /stacks to install de package?

and Another question, when I install that, to use my normal workspaces, should I source from the terminal? I mean, how can I use my normal workspaces: /home/lsi2/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks when I install that

Thanks a lot!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243255/%5Bsolved%5D-remove-all-ros_package_path/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hachbani](https://answers.ros.org/users/41595/hachbani/) on 2019-05-22**:
Hello,

Did you manage to get it to work ? I'm started feeling not optimistic at all about this BLAM thing after struggling for days to get the update file to work.. kind of tried every relevant suggestion I found on Internet

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-22**:
@hachbani: what are you referring to with "BLAM thing"?

**Comment by [hachbani](https://answers.ros.org/users/41595/hachbani/) on 2019-05-22**:
@gvdhoom What I'm referring to is the first step to build the BLAM, when I run sudo ./update (Without the sudo I get a lot of permission denied errors) I get the following errors: https://pastebin.com/9E6754Vp
I removed the catkin_ws path from ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, I only have /opt/ros/kinetic/share.

I think it's because of the catkin_make_isolated.. but can't figure out why it doesn't work neither how to fix it

Any suggestion please ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-22**:
"BLAM" is not something I recognise. If you're referring to something that is known in a particular community, please explain or provide a link.

Finally, I would recommend you post a new question instead of commenting on a 3 year old one that has already been answered.

**Comment by [hachbani](https://answers.ros.org/users/41595/hachbani/) on 2019-05-22**:
Will do, thanks for ur time!
I posted my question here as a reply cause it' relevant to the post since OP had kind of the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should just remove `home/dan/catkin_ws/src` from `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, and run `update`.

Then If something wrong, you should remove `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, and run `update`.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-09-08**:
yeah i forgot to post the solution, first one is right, you only have to delete the part refering to your personal workspaces, works fine thanks